# angular2 filereader mysteriously fails

Tags: html, angular, rxjs, filereader

I'm using the setup shown below to read image file in angular2. I'm using `input` element to show the window to choose file and then trigger the `addThumbnail` function when the file is chosen. The click on the `input` is being triggered by another button. I noticed that the trigger of `addThumbnail` function sometimes fails silently i.e. the function is not even triggered after choosing a file. This happens may be 1 out of 5 times I'm not sure if this could happen because of the size of the file. I tried to debug this by setting a breakpoint inside `addThumbnail` function but that is not even being triggered.

```
<div class="extra-image-container">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="addThumbnail($event)" style="display:none;" #fileInput2/>
    <div class="thumbnail-button" (click)="fileInput2.click()">
        <span><i class="material-icons">photo_camera</i></span><br>
        <span>Extra Images</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the addThumbnail function and the file reader function I'm using.

```
addThumbnail(event) {
    console.log('adding thumbnail');
    var subscription = this.readImage(event.target).subscribe((result) => {
        this.thumbnails.push(result.imageUrl);
        this.editedThumbnails.push(result.imageUrl);
        subscription.unsubscribe()
    });
}

readImage(inputValue: any) : Observable<any> {
    var file:File = inputValue.files[0]; 
    var myReader:FileReader = new FileReader();
    var observable = new Observable(observer => {
        myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
            observer.next({imageUrl: myReader.result});
            console.log("image loaded");
            // var image = new Image();
            // image.addEventListener("load", () => {
            //     observer.next({
            //         imageWidth: image.width,
            //         imageHeight: image.height,
            //         imageSize: file.size/1000,
            //         imageUrl: myReader.result
            //     })
            //     console.log("image loaded");
            // })
            // image.src = myReader.result;
        }
        myReader.readAsDataURL(file);//triggers the callback
    })
    return observable
}
```

Comment: it will be nice to look at logs

Comment: Your code is correctly working on Chrome 60. By the way, `subscription.unsubscribe();` seems useless.

Comment: @LudovicGuillaume that was part of trial and error but thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @slesh not sure how to produce logs since the functions are not even being called

Comment: What about your test environment? (ng version, cli version, browser...)

Comment: Chrome Version 59.0, angular cli 1.2.0. I made a video showing the problem: https://youtu.be/2A2m1KWr_So seems like it is still being processed

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYHeQKLeweE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Okay so I figured out why there is an error: if I read a file, remove it, and then read the same file again, the read doesn't work. Not sure how to solve this problem though.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you read same file one after another, then the `change` is not triggered because the files are same. So, to fix this all I had to do was set the value of input element to empty string after a file is loaded.

```
@ViewChild('fileInput2') private thumbImageInput: ElementRef;
// and in the addThumbnail method: 
addThumbnail(event) {
    var subscription = this.readImage2(event.target).subscribe((result) => {
        this.thumbnails.push(result.imageUrl);
        this.editedThumbnails.push(result.imageUrl);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(result.imageUrl);
        this.thumbImageInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    });
}
```